# How to implement a function with char array on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, wifi, esp8266

I am doing a sketch using an ESP8266 as a WiFi server, I need to send a character string to the Client, for this I am using this piece of code:

```
  char sbuf[] = "Hello world!\n\r";
  size_t len = strlen(sbuf);
  for (i = 0; i < MAXCLIENTS; i++) {
  if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()) {
     serverClients[i].write((char*) &sbuf, len);
     delay(1);
   }
 }
```

It works OK, the client can receive the characters.

But now I want to make a function to call it the times I need it, this is the function code:

```
void sendDataToClient( char *sbuf[]) {
size_t len = strlen(sbuf);
for (i = 0; i < MAXCLIENTS; i++) {
if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()) {
  serverClients[i].write((char*) &sbuf, len);
  delay(1);
  }
 }
}
```

That's I'm calling the function:

```
char bufferMSGtoClient[] = "Hello world!\n\r";

sendDataToClient(bufferMSGtoClient)
```

But it doesn't work, the client does not receive anything, someone can tell me what is my error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sizeof doesn’t do what you think it does here.  You’re getting 4 because that’s the size of a pointer.  Use strlen instead.  It will tell you how long up to the \n.  Add two if you want the \r too.

```
void sendDataToClient( char *sbuf[]) {
```

This line is also not doing what you think.  It is passing an array of pointers.  You either want a pointer OR an array, but certainly not an array of pointers.

```
void sendDataToClient( char *sbuf) {
```

and

```
serverClients[i].write((char*) &sbuf, len);
```

should be

```
serverClients[i].write(sbuf, len);
```

I'm betting.

Comment: `Delta`, I have made the change, I still get the value of `len` 4 and the client does not receive anything

Comment: You're also passing in an array of pointers.  Lose the brackets on the argument sbuf.